# Integrity constraint violation in Zend_db

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, inner-join, mysql-error-1052

I have the following code:

```
$selectColumns= array('user_id.user_email',
                    'user_details.first_name', 
                    'user_details.last_name', 
                    'user_details.zip', 
                    'user_details.store_id');
$result = $handle->select()->from('user_id')
                           ->where('uid=?', $uid)
                           ->columns($selectColumns)
                           ->join('user_details', 'user_id.uid = user_details.uid')
                           ->query(ZEND_DB::FETCH_OBJ);
```

After I run, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: '
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'uid' in where clause is ambiguous
```

I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `uid=?` in your `WHERE` clause. As a `uid` column is in both tables `user_id` and `user_details` MySQL cannot determine which column you really want to use. You must therefore do

```
// [...]
->where('user_id.uid=?', $uid)
// [...]
```

Answer (score -1):

check the generated sql query in the log. Maybe you have to put the where clause after the join.